# MPI programming get external file

Tags: c, mpi, cluster-computing, mpich

i have problem, how to read external file.txt on my mpi code on C. into file.txt containing 10000 word, and i will filter this word remove symbol and number, and i get output like this :

```
A
As
America
And
Are
Aztec

B
Bald
Bass
Best

up to Z
```

my question is, how to process it on parallel computing?

Comment: 1. Read your file to memory using file memory mapping;
2. Use a variation of multi-threaded merge sort on your data.

Comment: this smells like homework

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear if you are asking about the MPI_File routines for parallel i/o, or if you are asking how to processs a file in MPI.  I'm going to assume you're asking about MPI_File routines.

For unformatted text files, it can be difficult to come up with a parallel decomposition strategy. your file has 10000 words including symbol and number so it's not actually a whole lot of data.

if you know how to use the POSIX system calls `open`, `read`, and `close`, then you can in a first pass simply replace those calls with `MPI_File_open`, `MPI_File_read`, and `MPI_File_close`.

you can ignore details like the MPI file view, in-memory datatypes, and collective I/O: your data is probably not large enough to warrant more sophisticated techniques.